# get jquery script to work with prototype?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

Him

Im trying to convert my jQuery script to a Prototype compatible one, but i cant seem to get it to work. Can someone please help me? Basically what it does is allow you to click an entire html table row to check/uncheck a checkbox.

```
$('input:checkbox').hide()
$('.clickable tr').click(function() {
var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox').filter(':first');
$checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant markup too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Prototype you use [`$$()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) to select elements with css-like selectors.

This returns an [`Array`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/) of [`Elements`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/). Then you could use the [`.each()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/each/) method on the returned value:

```
$$('input:checkbox').each(function(e) { e.hide(); });
```

For events, you use the [`Element.observe()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/observe/) method:

```
$$('.clickable tr').each(function(e) {
    e.observe(function(event) {
        var checkbox = $(this).select('[type="checkbox"]:first');
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        $(this).addClassName('selected');
    });
});
```

(untested)

Comment: Hmmm I copied your code exactly into an external file called "checkbox.js" and included it (tested the path, it is correct) and its not working.. Even the first part that hides the checkboxes..

Comment: Has I said it's untested; I given you some indications, now you can write the code yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

use the word jQuery instead of $ also read this: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Do i need to have jquery installed to do this? Ive heard you cant use both jquery and prototype installed on the same app

Comment: you can add both of the but you need to call  jQuery.noConflict(); right after the call for jQuery - <script src="prototype.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you are looking to for dual compatibility of js libraries consider using the `$.noConflict()` and use `jQuery` everywhere instead of `$`.

If you are looking to toggle a checkbox value simply by clicking the row, below is how you would do it in jQuery. here, is the working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/myCjg/).

```
$(function(){
    $('tr').click(function(){
        var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').first();
        if(checkbox.attr("checked")){
            checkbox.removeAttr("checked");
        }
        else{
            checkbox.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: my site uses many Prototype scripts and only one small jquery so i feel like itd be easier to just convert the one jquery to prototype..